# How to combine two json objects connected by foreign key in angular?

Tags: json, angularjs

need to display in table data from two json objects, connected by foreign key.

The first json is:

```
$scope.items = [
    {status_id: 1,type:1},
    {status_id: 2,type:2},
    {status_id: 1,type:3},
    {status_id: 1,type:4}
];
```

The second json is:

```
var statuses = [
    {status_id: 1, status_name: 'Confirmed'},
    {status_id: 2, status_name: 'Processed'}
];
```

In my table i want to see like this:

```
confirmed  1
processed  2
confirmed  3
confirmed  4
```

How can I do it in angular?

Comment: Create a third array manipulating the first two. Loop through objects in items, foreach check status_id in statuses and add status_name to your new object ? as you would without Angular?

Comment: make use of the filter function within ng-repeat

Comment: Did the answer below address your question?

Answer (score 1):

This is not so much an "Angular" question, as it is a Javascript question. Create a third array with all the data.

Alternatively, if `statuses` was an associative array (or an object) with `status_id` as the key, it would make things much simpler:

```
$scope.statuses = { 1: {status_id: 1, status_name: "Confirmed"},
                    2: {status_id: 2, status_name: "Processed"} };
```

Then you could just `ng-repeat` over your `items`:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  {{statuses[item.status_id].status_name}}  {{item.type}}
</div>
```